# Displaying a many-to-many relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

**Background:**
I have the following models for a visitor management app. Each site can have multiple visitors and each visitor can visit multiple sites. I am unable to find a way to show a list of visitors on each site or show a list of sites a visitor has visited. I have removed unnecessary fields.

**.models.py**

```
class Site(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
  accomodation = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  visitors = models.ManyToManyField('Visitor', blank=True)

class Visitor(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
  ...
```

**admin.py**

```
class AdminArea(admin.AdminSite):
  
vms_admin = AdminArea(name='vms_admin')

@admin.register(Site, site=vms_admin)
class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fieldsets = (*removed*)
  list_display = [*removed*]
  list_filter = (*removed*)

@admin.register(Visitor, site=vms_admin)
class VisitorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fieldsets = (*removed*)
  list_display = [*removed*]
  list_filter = (*removed*)
```

**Django Admin**

This is how the list of sites looks:
[Django Admin Site List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFtkT.png)

This is how the list of visitors look like:
[Django Admin Visitor List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmgXC.png)

**Question**
How do I show the list of visitors for each site and vice versa?
For example:
If I click on Gingin Gravity Precinct, I want to see the list of visitors associated with it, in a table, below "site details". Similar to the list of visitors shown, but specific to the site.
[Django Admin Specific Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC8uz.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would make the related_name explicit in model Site. This is not strictly necessary, there is a default backward reference created by Django, I just never remember the name of that, so I like to be explicit.

```
visitors = models.ManyToManyField('Visitor', blank=True, related_name='sites')
```

I assume you want to see the list of sites when you click a single Visitor, in other words, on the visitor detail admin page. In that case, all you need to do is to specify the field `sites` in the VisitorAdmin. Vice versa to display visitors in the SiteAdmin. You will get a list of all visitors then, in which the active ones are selected.

```
class SiteAdmin(Admin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('Visitors', {'fields': ('visitors')})
    )
```

If you want to display a (possibly long) list of sites in the visitor list admin page, what you can do is to define a property on the Visitor model, and add that property to the `list_fields`.

```
class Visitor(Model):
    @property
    def list_of_sites(self):
        return self.sites.all().values_list(name, flat=True)

class SiteAdmin(Admin):
    list_display = ['name', 'accomodation', 'list_of_sites']
```